# InnoDB locking a row to prevent multiple concurrent sessions from reading it

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I'm using InnoDB.

I have table A

```
ID | DATA
1  | Something
2  | something else
```

table B

```
user_id | DATA
1       | NULL
```

my program reads a row from table A and updates table B, then deletes the row from table A after the update statement.

is it possible for two users (2 different concurrent sessions) to read the same row from table A?  how can I avoid that?

that's my program

```
$core = Database::getInstance();
$q = $core->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tableA` LIMIT 1");
$q->execute();
$result = $q->fetch();

$q = $core->dbh->prepare("UPDATE `tableB` SET `data` = ? where `user_id`= ?");
$q->execute(array($result['data'],$ID));
```

// how to prevent a second user from reading the same row before the next statement gets executed

```
$q = $core->dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `tableA`  where `ID`= ?");
$q->execute(array($result['ID']));
```

Comment: your code deletes from B, the text says A

Comment: the select could go in a subquery of the update. and yes i believe so, so you want to add  table lock, but i'm hoping some one smarter posts an answer

Comment: Do not be too concerned about preventing reading by others as, for example, they could have read the record minutes earlier but not refreshed their screen yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) which puts an exclusive lock onto the row (at least if the transaction isolation level is set to somewhat reasonable).

This only works if the storage engine of the table is InnoDB. Also you have to execute all queries inside of the same transaction (so execute `BEGIN` query at the beginning and `COMMIT` at the end).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps and makes clear the view of what you want to achieve.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html